# Is OAuth suitable for this scenario?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth

I'm new to OAuth and I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand with my problem. I need to create a simple web application for track expenses, with some basic actions (user must be able to create an account and log in, list expenses, edit them, etc) with a REST API for each one, and the trick is that I need to be able to pass credentials to both the webpage and the API. So, after some research I've found some examples using Digest Authentication and HMAC Authentication but lot of posts also mentioned OAuth as an alternative approach, so my question is, given this scenario, would be proper to use OAuth? I mean, as far as I understand OAuth is suitable when you want to share resources with other application, which I'm not doing for this project; besides that, when you try to access the shared resource it appears a page requesting permission for the foreign application, would that page appear at some point in my application? (maybe after the login?)
Thanks in advance guys

Comment: This question belongs to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your current scenario it does not make sense to use OAuth. It's not what OAuth is designed for.
2. If your application ecosystem is going to have multiple webapps running on a single SSO (like google) then it is very helpful to have OAuth.

Suggestion: Decide based on your business/operation plan and implement accordingly.

Note: If you plan to have 10 apps in the span of the next 5 years but only have one app now it does not make sense to spend time to implement complex protocols like OAuth right now. Scale as you grow.

Comment: Hi @Jit B, thank you for your answer, I've published the question in programmers.stackexchange and got some extra help.